# How to convert textarea value to a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the textarea input value to a string, but does not work and output is: [Object HTMLInputElement], I've used regex, it works properly when I hard code a string

```
let input = document.getElementById("input").toString();
  let result = input.replace(/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g, i => i.toUpperCase());
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: `let input = document.getElementById("input").value;` You want to access the **value** of the textarea, not the element itself.

Comment: let textareaValue = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
I did but still not work

Comment: let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
let textareaValue = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
const sentenceTransform = () => {
  let result = textareaValue.replace(/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g, i =>
    i.toUpperCase()
  );
  console.log(result);
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the `value` of the `<textarea>` each time its content changes. The "input" event can be used for this.

```js
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
textarea.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  let result = textarea.value.replace(/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g, i => i.toUpperCase());
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: I've a little bit bug still, I want to transform it only when I click,     textarea.style.textTransform = result;
I used this but not working, it start works on next input, I want all text to transform onclick

Comment: @SAKSoomro You can create a button and add a click event listener instead.

Comment: I did but not worked,
const sentenceTransform = () => {
    textarea.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
      let result = textarea.value.replace(/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g, i =>
        i.toUpperCase()
      );
      textarea.style.textTransform = result;
      // console.log(result);
    });
};
and placed in HTML onclick function

Comment: @SAKSoomro This appears to be a different issue then, so I would recommend asking a new question with a [mre].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250593/discussion-between-saksoomro-and-unmitigated).

Answer (score 1):

The value of textarea is already string, you just need to extract it the right way, which is using textarea.value

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let value = input.value;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<textarea id="input">This textarea value</textarea>
```

Comment: let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
let textareaValue = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
const sentenceTransform = () => {
  let result = textareaValue.replace(/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g, i =>
    i.toUpperCase()
  );
  console.log(result);
};

this is complete code if I'm selecting value it returns empty in console

Comment: sentenceTransform is a function so you need to call it if you want to see the result, you can call it using sentenceTransform();
https://jsfiddle.net/benalizakaria/hpm8owky/